# is it possible to fake the amsart class format?

Tags: document-classes, titlesec, amsthm, amsart, ntheorem

I often use the amsart documentclass. I like it because it is very compact (it also seems to be an industry standard in my area).
What I don't like about it is that I'm not able to use kpfonts or ntheorem with it.

So my question is: does anyone have a solution to this problem?

One solution might be that I'm incompetent with latex and therefore it is actually possible to use kpfonts with amsart.

The other solution I thought is by using some package like titlesec to get all the formatting (including toc?) the same as amsart. So then the question becomes: have you already figured out how to do that and would you mind telling me? (I agree this solution is a bit dumb)

EDIT: an example of what goes wrong with ntheorem is as follows

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
    MWE
\end{document}
```

it brings up an error (Package ntheorem Error: theoremstyle plain already defined)

Comment: Can you place in the question a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043) that demonstrates the problems that you are having? It is difficult to know what is wrong without it.

Comment: nevermind, it seems I just made the whole thing up.

Comment: ok, that was quite embarrassing. in any case ntheorem definitely is incompatible and I won't delete the question as I believe it is still valid.

Comment: Still need an MWE! ;)

Comment: never! ... ok, to be serious I guess I would have to say that I change the question to "how to mimic amsart with titlesec".

Comment: Notice also that if you want just the *compactness*, you can use the `savetrees` package.

Comment: This is too broad a question. Perhaps ask about some particular aspect of mimicking `amsart` to overcome some particular incompatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Why cannot you use kpfonts with amsart?

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kpfonts,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Update**  OP asked to put theorem number on margins using `amsart`.

Actually `amsart` provides full access to formatting theorem headings with the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle` command.  See the commented code in `amsclass.dtx`.  Here is how to produce margin number:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newtheoremstyle{marginnum}%
   {\topskip}%            Space above
   {\topskip}%            Space below
   {\itshape}%            Body font
   {}%                    Indent amount
   {\bfseries}%           Theorem head font
   {.}%                   Punctuation after theorem head
   {\newline}%            Space after theorem head
   {\makebox[0pt]{\thmnumber{#2}\hspace{2em}}\thmname{#1}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
                     %    Theorem head spec 
\theoremstyle{marginnum}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[Fermat]
  For $n>2$ the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ cannot be satisfied with
  positive integer $a$, $b$ and $c$.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are correct (my bad!) kpfonts is fine (although ntheorem isn't). thanks for that.

Comment: If you tell what exactly do you want from `ntheorem`, I can try to find a solution using `amsart` functionality

Comment: for example theorems with the numbering on the margin.

Comment: Please see the update